# My iOS app crashes before received a Parse push notification (iOS 7)

Tags: ios7, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I had an iOS 7 app compiled and in the App Store. The app uses Parse backend and push notifications.

Before the released of the iOS 8 version (yesterday), the app received an push today, but the app crashes.

It's posible that Parse sended some additional payload that make crash the app?

This is the AppDelegate code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // Aquí se llega cuando se recibe una push y la aplicación está abierta
    NSLog(@"Se recibe una push con la app abierta: %@", userInfo);
    //[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    if ([userInfo objectForKey:kPushCampoEventoId]) {
        [TierraDeTorosUtils cargaEventoConIdentificador:[userInfo objectForKey:kPushCampoEventoId]
                                           enController:self.window.rootViewController];
    }
}
```

And the backend js code in Parse:

```
 Parse.Push.send({
    channels: [request.params.channel],
    data: {
        alert: request.params.mensaje,
        badge: 1,
        title: "Tierra de Toros",
        evento_id: request.params.evento_id
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please show us your AppDelegate's didReceiveNotification functions, as well as your Parse push code.

Comment: Added code. I'm afraid that Parse will fix it in the new iOS8 SDK.

Comment: Did you forget the closing parenthesis? Also would you put a break point in didReceiveRemoteNotification to see which line causes the crash? If that doesn't work, join me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61287/parse-com).